# Cant import date field from csv to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Here is the function to upload csv data to mysql in codeigniter. Problem is uploading birthday. In csv date are as 13/5/2015. After uploading date field uploaded as null. Other fields are ok. How do I fix it.

```
function importcsv()
{
    $data['addressbook'] = $this->csv_model->get_addressbook();
    $data['error'] = ''; //initialize image upload error array to empty
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    // If upload failed, display error

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
    }
    else {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_path = './uploads/' . $file_data['file_name'];
        if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) {
            $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);
            foreach($csv_array as $row) {
                $insert_data = array(
                    'firstname' => $row['firstname'],
                    'lastname' => $row['lastname'],
                    'birthday' => $row['birthday'],
                    'email' => $row['email'],
                );
                $this->csv_model->insert_csv($insert_data);
            }

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully');
            redirect(base_url() . 'csv');

            // echo "<pre>"; print_r($insert_data);

        }
        else $data['error'] = "Error occured";
        $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: WHat is the date format on csv?

Comment: Date format 13/5/2015

Comment: Change the format before inserting to db as db format is `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572797/import-csv-to-mysql-and-convert-date

Comment: db date format already yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 4):

Use `DateTime` Object for date conversions and mysql native data types needs date to be in `Y-m-d` format. So you need to add these

```
foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
    $bday = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/n/Y',$row['birthday']);
    $insert_data = array(
     'firstname'=>$row['firstname'],
     'lastname'=>$row['lastname'],
     'birthday'=>$bday->format("Y-m-d"),
     'email'=>$row['email'],
    );
    $this->csv_model->insert_csv($insert_data);
}
```

Comment: Another problem, when there is no date then return: Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean

Comment: Yes I would suggest to add a condition as `if(strlen($row['birthday']) > 5){  //add the conversion code here and keep $bday->format("Y-m-d") in a variable say $mbday  }else{$mbday=''; }` and use `$mbday` in the array, but need to make sure if the dates are present then it has the given format. Or better using try-catch and in the catch block set the value as ''.

Answer (score 1):

Convert date string to proper format and use.

**Change**:

```
'birthday'=>$row['birthday'],
```

**To**:

```
'birthday'=>date_format(date_create_from_format('d/M/Y', $row['birthday']), 'Y-m-d') ),
```

**Refer to documentation**:

- [**DateTime::createFromFormat**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

  - Returns new DateTime object formatted according to the specified
    format

Comment: Bro, Getting error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php

Line Number: 552

Answer (score 0):

Change the `format` of the `date` -

```
'birthday'=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '.', $row['birthday'])))
```

`Date` format for database column is `YYYY-MM-DD`. And you are passing `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: Bro, Getting error A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Array to string conversion Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php Line Number: 552

Comment: `var_dump($row['birthday'])`  and show what you are getting.